# 10 bit YUV byte array to BufferedImage

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage, yuv

I have an array of bytes that represent raw pixel data of a 10 bit YUV image.

How can i convert this to a buffered image? I've been trying to look at the Raster.class, but i'm struggling to understand if its possible via this as because the image is 10bit, each pixel will be 3.75 bytes (10 bits, 3 colour channels, 8 bits per byte = 10*3 / 8).

Comment: I guess you could perform a [YUV to RGB conversion](https://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php) first, then feed that to the `BufferedImage`?

Comment: As @domdom says, convert the YUV values to RGB first. Then pad each component from 10 to 16 bit (there's no eays way to work with "packed" values > 8 bit in Java2D, AFAIK) . Create a `Raster` from this data, and use a `ComponentColorModel` with normal RGB color space and 10 significant bits per component, to finally create the `BufferedImage`.